# Matlab left - division in vectors?

Tags: matlab, division

> > x=[1;2;3]

x =

```
 1
 2
 3
```

> > y=[4;5;6]

y =

```
 4
 5
 6
```

> > x\y

ans =

```
2.2857
```

How did Matlab find that result ? (I searched many forums but I did not understand what they told.I would like to know the algorithm which gave this result.)

Answer (score 5):

From MATLAB documentation of `\`:

If A is an `M-by-N` matrix with `M < or > N` and B is a column vector with M components, or a matrix with several such columns, then `X = A\B` is the solution in the least squares sense to the under- or overdetermined system of equations `A*X = B`.

Here your system is not under/over-determined. Since both have 3 rows. So you can visualize your equation as:

```
xM=y
M=inv(x)*y
```

Now, since your matrix is not square, it will calculate the pseudo-inverse using SVD. Therefore,

```
M=pinv(x)*y;
```

You will get value of M as 2.2857.

Another explanation can be: It will give you the solution of `xM=y` in the sense of least squares. You can verify this as follows:

```
M=lsqr(x,y)
```

This will give you the value of M = 2.2857.

You can always do `help \` in MATLAB command window to get more information.

You are encouraged to check more details about the least squares and pseudo-inverse.

Answer (score -1):

This documentation should explain it

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html

Here is a link to the algorithm

http://www.maths.lth.se/na/courses/NUM115/NUM115-11/backslash.html

You can see the source inside matlab much more easily though. (I don't have it locally so I can't check but the source of a lot of matlab functions is available inside matlab)