# What does a/b do in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I got some matlab code that contains the expression:

```
a/b
```

where a and be are 1D arrays. What does it do?

E.g.:

```
a= [1 2 3];
b= [1 1 1];
a/b
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: The command is called `mrdivide` as given [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15169301/1586200) answer for information on `mldivide`. Similarly `mrdivide` can be explained.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` should be treated as matrices and the answer to `c=a/b` is then equivalent to minimizing error of the equation system `a=b*c`. Or in another word, minimizing the error of `bc-a`, which expands to `∑(cb_i - a_i)²`. Since we want to minimize for `c` this can be done by taking the first derivative w.r.t. c and setting equal to zero. Working this out yields the expression `c=∑(a_i*b_i)/∑(b_i²)` or in matlab:

```
sum(a.*b)/sum(b.*b)
```

This can be tried e.g. by doing:

```
a = [ 1 2 3];
b = [ 1 2 1];
a/b
sum(a.*b)/sum(b.*b)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `c = a / b` should be equivalent of `c = a * inv(b)`. Which is the solution for `c * b = a`. Look: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in MATLAB are used to solve linear system of matrices.
My thumb of rule is that the matrix which is close to the upper side of the slash is "Inverted".
Though one must remember that the actual algorithm for solving is doesn't use the explicit inverted matrix (For numerical stability and speed considerations).

Have a look at:

- [`mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)
- [`mrdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)

So the equation $ Ax = b $ would be solved by `x = A \ b` which is "Equivalent" of `x = inv(A) * b`.
The equation $ xA = b $ would be solved by `x = b / A` which is "Equivalent" of `x = b * inv(A)`.